# Homomorphism between coherent sheaves concentrated in one point

Tags: algebraic-geometry, sheaf-theory, coherent-sheaves

I am reading the book “Fourier-Mukai transforms in algebraic geometry" by Daniel Huybrechts. In the proof of Lemma 4.5 in page 92, he uses

**Lemma:** If $M$ is a finite module over a local ring $(A,m)$ such that $\operatorname{supp}(M)=\{m\}$, then there exists a surjection $M\twoheadrightarrow A/m$ and an injection $A/m\hookrightarrow M$.

and he concludes that if $\mathcal{F}$ and $\mathcal{G}$ are two coherent sheaves over a smooth projective variety $X$ such that $\operatorname{Supp}(\mathcal{F})=\operatorname{Supp}(\mathcal{G})=\{x\}$, then there exists a homomorphism $\mathcal{F}\to \mathcal{G}$. My question is that why is this true?

Comment: Suppose in an affine subset $\mathcal{F} = \widetilde{M}$ and $\mathcal{G} = \widetilde{N}$ . Then I think by definition of support we have $\widetilde{M} = \widetilde{M_{\mathfrak{m}_{x}}}$ and $\widetilde{N} = \widetilde{N_{\mathfrak{m}_{x}}}$. Is the composition $M_{\mathfrak{m}_{x}} \twoheadrightarrow A/m \hookrightarrow N_{\mathfrak{m}_{x}}$ what you are looking for?

Comment: What do you mean exactly with *a finite $A$-module*?  A module with finite cardinality, or a finitely generated module?

Comment: @Bernard a finitely generated module

Comment: @hyyyyy Here, why do we have $\widetilde{M}=\widetilde{M_{\mathfrak{m}_x}}}$ and $\widetilde{M}=\widetilde{M_{\mathfrak{m}_x}}}$?

Comment: @PouyaLayeghi This comes from the definition of $\widetilde{M}$.

Comment: @hyyyyy I guess it is true on principal affine open subsets, not on all affine opens and I kind of got your idea.